# How does & bit operator work here?

Tags: java, collections, bit-manipulation

In Java Collection classes, I have noticed very often codes like below

```
  //ArrayDeque
    public E pollFirst() {
    int h = head;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E result = (E) elements[h];
    // Element is null if deque empty
    if (result == null)
        return null;
    elements[h] = null;     // Must null out slot
    head = (h + 1) & (elements.length - 1);
    return result;
}
```

What does `head = (h + 1) & (elements.length - 1);` do ?
   Why is & operator used here and what purpose does it serve.

My Question is not how & works, but what's its use here.

Can anyone explain it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a shortcut for `(h + 1) % elements.length` that only works if `elements.length` is a power of two. On some older hardware this may have run slightly faster, although I doubt this is still the case on a modern CPU.

Comment: I checked , default array length is set to 16 and is doubled  when full. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That `&` operation is not a *true* equivalent for `%`, think negative numbers. It's not the case here, but there are other places where this matters (like `HashMap`), where this is done via :

```
(n - 1) & hash // n - current capacity, hash - hashcode
```

Since `hashcode`s are int values - they can be negative numbers. Using `%` instead of `&` would result in a negative number, which simply can't happen for `HashMap` (since that is the bucket number).

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge share!!